# Swift web app: iPhone keyboard, top bar and layout

Tags: iphone, swift

I'm developing a web app in Swift. Normally, if the user click on a text field, the native keyboard opens itself. How can I remove from this keyboard the keyboard's top bar (with the "done" button and the arrows)? Ho can I resize my web view, if the keyboard is opened?

Thank in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove top bar from keyboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31695021/how-to-remove-top-bar-from-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

The options to customize the keyboard are quite limited, you can refer to [Configuring the Keyboard for Web Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW12) section:

> You can include autocorrect and autocapitalize attributes in the
>   definition of an input element to specify the keyboard’s behaviors...
>   You can also control which type of keyboard is displayed when a user
>   touches a text field in a web page...