# How to remove top bar from keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm developing a app for iOS using the language Swift, with a internal web view browser. If the user click on a text field, the native iOS keyboard open itself.

My simple question is: how can I hide the top bar (with the 2 arrows and the "done" button) in the keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

Why would you want to do that anyway? It is very useful for navigating forms on iOS.

Comment: I have to try this because is a specific of a software which I am now developing... Ok, if you are sure, I don't try any other solution.

Comment: If you are somehow trying to hack your way around `WKWebView`'s form management to build your own form, you will probably be better off designing the form on your own, without the `WKWebView` :)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK,Apple did not open webview keyboard interface.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like auto correction enabled  in the entry field , try setting textField.autocorrectiontype = .no . Hope this helps .